# Parent opacity has different effects for Chrome and Android on child SVG

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome

I have a  parent with an SVG child element (the SVG is a simple cube).  The  parent's CSS has opacity = 0.45.  It appears on Android/Webview that the opacity value is applied to the individual SVG polygons as they are rendered, causing me to see the inner walls of the cube. On desktop Chrome, the opacity value is applied after the SVG is rendered, so the cube looks solid/opaque but obviously translucent to the background.  The desktop version is what I would like to see on Android/Webview.  Why is there a difference between the two?  And is there any CSS trick to fix this that does not involve moving the opacity value from CSS to an SVG attribute?

Comment: Code. Must see the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have filed a report to Chromium before about this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596678
Once the hardware layer is replaced by the software layer, this issue should be resolved.